# Cannot Pass Parameter 1 by reference

Tags: php, syntax-error, runtime-error

so iam trying to check if an variable's values equals Array's last row `if($ver == end(Self::Supported_Version) {}` but it results In `Cannot Pass Parameter 1 by reference` ERROR...

My Code:-

```
namespace John; 
class SP {

const Supported_Version = array('a', 'b', 'c'); 

    public function VersionCheck()
    {
        return ($ver == end(Self::Supported_Version) ? (True)  : (False)); 
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can't create a reference to a constant because it can't be changed and `end()` takes the argument by reference.

Comment: ..., but you can simply copy the constant to a temp variable and use that: `$sv = Self::Supported_Version; return ($ver == end($sv) ? (True)  : (False));`

Comment: Or don't use a constant.  Why is it needed?

Comment: Oh... Thanks for both of you (@AbraCadaver @jh1711) It work as well. @AbraCadaver because it isn't going to be changed anymore it just contains an array with a list of Supported/Allowed Versions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create a reference to a constant because it can't be changed and `end()` takes the argument by reference.  If you really need a constant then assign to a temporary variable.  You can do this in the call.

Also, you don't need the ternary since the `==` comparison will return `true` or `false`:

```
return ($ver == end($s = Self::Supported_Version));
```

Comment: I found your answer while searching on a ksort error. This answer for me was to assign `$GLOBALS` to temp var $globals and the ksort the temp.